# Auto-pause Spotify when receiving a teams call

Tags: ubuntu, spotify

I want to start listing to music again during work, but receive a lot of Microsoft Teams calls. I am working on Ubuntu Linux and use Spotify.

Is there a script / software to auto-pause the music whenever a teams call is coming in?

There is

https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic (for Mac)

https://github.com/samjgalbraith/Spotify-auto-pause (for Windows)

and different questions to Microsoft and spotify, none with a solution.

Comment: I found that this might be supposed to happen automagically: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159104/how-to-stop-gnome-from-muting-my-music - but it does not for me, I am using teams-for-linux

Comment: https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/1000

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which will prioritize all audio streams without role over music, so also the teams streams:

```
$ pacmd unload-module module-role-cork
$ pacmd load-module module-role-cork trigger_roles=no_role global=1
```

[hint found here](https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/blob/13ef02da1bc55b8a36ff35ca5f9d15cf7495932a/src/modules/stream-interaction.c#L225)